# how to remove [ ] in the mailer

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

i'm using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage thro C# to send an email.
the issue is if sender's name is different and credential is diferent it shows like shankar[admin@mydomain.com]
i need to remove this set brackets [].

help me...
below is my coding.

```
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage oMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        oMail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("admin@mydomain.com", "shankar123");
        oMail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim());
        oMail.Subject = "Subject*";
        oMail.Body = "Body*";
        oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        smtp.Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
        System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = cred;
        smtp.Send(oMail);
```

Comment: Can you try clarifying this a little more? I am not following you. We are here to help. I have read this a couple times and I don't understand.

Comment: When User gets an email .... the from address shows Shankar[admin@contentraven.com]...but i need only the name Shankar

Comment: Didnt it depend on the email client how it displays the name/address, on wich you don't have any control?

Comment: It's not in your control. It's done by the mail **client program** used by whoever get the email.

Comment: You realize that this is how e-mail works, right? A message has to come from an e-mail address, and the mail client is going to show that address. You can use a fake or anonymized address, but many e-mail systems won't accept that unless at least the domain is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract "Shankar" from "Shankar[...]", you could simply use

```
string address = "Shankar[admin@contentraven.com]";
string name = address.Substring(0, address.IndexOf('[') - 1);
// here, name contains "Shankar"
```

If you are sending emails to your users, and wish their email client not to show your address: This can't be done.

Comment: +1 Simpler than my answer. I just used regex in case the mailer uses <> instead of [].

Answer (score 1):

If I am following you, then you can use a RegEx to extract the string you need, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="Shankar[admin@contentraven.com]";

      string re1="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))";   // Variable Name 1

      Regex r = new Regex(re1,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String var1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            Console.Write(var1.ToString()+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Shankar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage oMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        oMail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("one@gmail.com");
        oMail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim());
        oMail.Subject = "Subject*";
        oMail.Body = "Body*";
        oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        smtp.Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
        System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new  System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = cred;
        smtp.Send(oMail);
```

we need to provide a valid EmailId in From address
it works gud for me!!!